# StreamProvider: Avoid repetitive builds

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a Flutter project that uses a camera plugin. In this plugin, I calculate every FPS on every frame, and send the result back to Flutter using EventChannel. On Flutter end I'm using a StreamProvider to update just the TextWidget that displays real-time FPS.

On top of my widget tree:

```dart
StreamProvider<FPSData>.value(value: initiated==false? null : streamControllerFPS.stream)
```

I'm adding fps values to the streamController through

```dart
FPSData fpsData = new FPSData(event['fps'])
streamControllerFPS.add(fpsData);

class FPSData{
  int value;
  FPSData(dynamic data){
    value = data.round();
  }
}
```

In my TextWidget (bottom of my widget tree):

```dart
class FPSWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Building FPSWidget");
    FPSData fpsData;
    fpsData = Provider.of<FPSData>(context);
    if(fpsData==null)
      return Container();
    return Text("fps: "+fpsData.value.toString());
  }
}
```

All of this is working as expected: FPS Text Widget is redrawn every time I a new FPS value gets added to the stream.

Now, What I'd like to know is if there is any possibility of just redrawing the widget when FPS value changes. Example: if last FPS value was 31 and new value is also 31, I'd like to skip rebuilding the text widget.
I know this is pretty obvious with a ChangeNotifier, but I was hoping I could do the same with a StreamProvider.

So far I've tried 2 different solutions:

1. combining .where() and .listen() methods

```dart
StreamProvider<FPSData>.value(value: initiated==false? null : streamControllerFPS.stream.where((newFPS) => newFPS.value!=lastFPSValue))
```

I used .listen() method to save **lastFPSValue**. It seemed that Provider.of was only being called when FPS changed, but I was only getting a null value in my TextWidget, even after setting StreamController and Stream as broadcast.

2. adding `updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true`, but that also did not work out. It seems to be that the problem might have to due with the fact that a previous FPSData(31) is always different from a new FPSData(31). I have no clue how to make them equal.

If someone could help me with this I'd appreciate! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bool operator to FPSData class seems to have done the trick! I'm not going to consider this as the accepted answer yet, as there might be a more efficient/correct way of doing this.

```dart
@immutable
class FPSData{
  final value;
  FPSData(this.value){
  }
  bool operator ==(Object fpsDataCompare) {
    return ((fpsDataCompare as FPSData).value == value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provider has a neat widget called Selector that use the provided value and update the builder only if a condition is met (like when the values are different)

```
final value = context.select<FPSData, int>((FPSData fps) => fps.value); //this will update the fps value and rebuild only if the previous and new value are different
if(value == null) return Container();
return Text("fps: $value ");
```

This is the same as the Selector widget of the Provider package

```
return Selector<FPSData, int>(
  selector: (_, fps) => fps.value,
  shouldRebuild: (prev, curr) => prev != curr, //this compare the previous and current value, if you don't set this it will just use the default 
  //DeepCollectionEquality().equals(value, selected) which does the same, but works  too if the parameters are iterables (List, Map, etc)
  builder: (_, value, __) {
    if(value == null) return Container();
    return Text("fps: $value");
  },
);
```

The first code is actually a new implementation added in Provider 4.1.0 but less verbose, also the first one doesn't let you change the shouldREbuild method in case you want to apply some more logic than just checking if they are different

Also to add

> adding updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true, but that also did not work
> out. It seems to be that the problem might have to due with the fact
> that a previous FPSData(31) is always different from a new
> FPSData(31). I have no clue how to make them equal.

that's because you're returning true always, without checking if they're actualliy different or not, maybe try it like this

```
updateShouldNotify: (prev, curr) => prev?.value != curr?.value
```

Now it will check if the values are different and notify if they are